# Is it possible to set the font style in an entire c# windows application

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set the font style in an entire c# windows application like CSS in a Web application?

Comment: Is it Windows Form or Windows Store App or others?

Comment: its windows appln only.

Answer (score 0):

In config,

```
WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Bold);
```

You can add before InitializeComponent() in the Form constructor(s):

```
this.Font = SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont;
```

Comment: Thanks, But I placed near InitializeComponent in Parent form its not working.

Comment: i modified the answer, please check

Comment: sorry, not able to change the size. I need separate class for all the style control like size,color,etc. want to call that class in all the forms?

Comment: then put in app.config

Comment: Thanks sajee..!, Am new in C#. can you please send any sample?